# Activity en android studio no muestra contenido, pero tampoco devuelve error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Buenas tardes a todos.

Estoy empezando a desarrollar en Android y tengo un problema a la hora de llamar a un segundo activity. Ya la tengo definida y en el XML sus botones y todo como lo quiero, pero el problema es que cuando hago click en el main activity para que inicie la segunda actividad, me aparece un alert (que yo he puesto ahí) como que estoy en el segundo activity, pero no me aparecen los botones... Como digo, estoy empezando con kotlin y Android... No tengo muy claro que código adjuntar, pero voy a poner el main.xml, mi activity2.kt y el activity2.xml

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

**MAIN**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="PAC Desarrollo"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagen"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="277dp"
        android:text="Ir a Activity 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="278dp"
        android:text="Ir a Acrtivity 3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ACTIVITY2.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity2">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PracticaDesarrollo.AppBarOverlay"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="419dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.PracticaDesarrollo.PopupOverlay" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCrear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Crear Tabla"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="48dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="181dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btInsertar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insertar Datos"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="209dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="177dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btConsultar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Consultar Datos"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="45dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btVolver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Volver"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="276dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity2.kt**

```
package com.example.practicadesarrollo
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var btCrear: Button
    private lateinit var btInsertar: Button
    private lateinit var btConsultar: Button
    private lateinit var btVolver: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        btCrear = findViewById(R.id.btCrear)
        btInsertar = findViewById(R.id.btInsertar)
        btConsultar = findViewById(R.id.btConsultar)
        btVolver = findViewById(R.id.btVolver)



        /*findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }*/


        btCrear.setOnClickListener({
            val intent = Intent(this, CrearTabla::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        btInsertar.setOnClickListener({
            intent = Intent(this, InsertarDatos::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        btConsultar.setOnClickListener({
            intent = Intent(this, ConsultarDatos::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        btVolver.setOnClickListener({
            intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        })

        this.showAlertDialog()

    }


    private fun showAlertDialog() {
        val alertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@Activity2)
        alertDialog.setTitle("")
        alertDialog.setMessage("Usted está en la activity 2")
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(
                "yes"
        ) { _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this@Activity2, "Alert Cerrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(
                "No"
        ) { _, _ -> }
        val alert: AlertDialog = alertDialog.create()
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        alert.show()
    }


}
```

Comentar que tengo código comentado en la segunda actividad.kt porque si lo dejo, se me cierra la aplicación en el emulador... No se a que se debe

Comment: El código comentado te crashea porque estás inflando R.layout.activity_2 y el R.id.fab no está en este xml

Comment: @ManuelMato y como debería de hacerlo para que no fallara¿?? gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Respecto al crash, no puedes referenciar a vistas que son null, en este caso no se ha inflado el xml y  la estás buscando con findViewById.  Si la Activity2 carga el Xml2, sí puedes referenciar a las vistas de ese xml pero no otro (no sin haberlo inflado en ese contexto).  Además no tiene sentido referenciar a una vista que no está visible para el usuario (el focus lo tiene otra activity)

Comment: @ManuelMato no se a que te refieres con el inflado. Soy nuevo en Android...

Comment: Cuando haces setContentView(R.id.tu_layout) es cuando puedes acceder a las vistas declaradas dentro del xml y no antes, si intentas acceder antes, el resultado de findViewById será null. Con inflar una vista me refiero a cargar el xml dentro de un objeto.  Lo que hace setContentView es añadir tu xml a la jerarquía de vistas de la actividad, momento en el que el usuario verá tu diseño y momento en el cual podrás acceder a esas vistas (accedes por referencia findViewById y la casteas a un objeto)

Comment: @ManuelMato realmente ese fragmento de código que tengo comentado, no influye para nada, es decir, podría cargar mi vista sin problema¿? si lo quito, me va al activity 2 pero no me muestra los botones que tengo, me siento muy perdido...

Comment: Yo creo que sí te está cargando la activity 2, lo que pasa es que la vista parece que no está bien construída.  Si usas ConstraintLayout, intenta que las vistas del viewgroup tengan enlaces al propio viewgroup usando atributos como layout_constraintTop_toTopOf, etc. mira la doc https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout Y cuando tengas dudas de si realmente te carga el layout o no, usa el layout por defecto con el hello world y verás que sí te carga.  También puedes hacer el codelab de Google sobre vistas y verás todo ésto.

Comment: @ManuelMato así es, no me estaba cargando bien el layout. He borrado todo y definido uno nuevo y colocado sus botones con sus referencias y todo bien y ya si funciona todo!